# KDE workspace gone after update 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, network-manager, kde

Yesterday (21 Oct 2014) my development machine said it had to be restarted due to an update. After rebooting and logging in I got no desktop manager. There happened to be an open konsole.

After trying a bunch of things I started muon and found that my KDE workspace is broken.

The problem is that I can't start the networking as I cant get to the network manager applet. Then I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and open a command line session and found that ifup doesn't work due to networkmanager settings. But I can't find the config files.

So how do I start the network from the commandline? What are the commands to get the KDE workspace package re-installed?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that accessing the network enables you to re-install the needed packages, so maybe that fixes your problem.

First, disable network-manager for the running session:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Next, try to bring up your network ethernet device (wlan is much more complicated on command line) and fire a dhcp client:

```
sudo ifup eth0
sudo dhclient eth0
```

If everything works fine you might have an address now and can reinstall everything you need via:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kde-workspace lightdm-kde-greeter
```

Comment: I disagree. The title fits the description. The workspace doesn't come up and the network doesn't either. Fixing the workspace is his priority. It's unclear if he **needs** internet access to fix his workspace.

Comment: Hm... I give you that the main priority is to get the workspace running, but the core problem right now seems to be the network as far as I see it... let's see what brings the solution.

Comment: It is the core problem in your **answer** because your fix needs network access.

Comment: Yes, didn't his question mention that he has network access, but the network configuration is not correct? I assumed that might help. If I am on the wrong track, I'm sorry that I tried.

Comment: Don't be sorry. I think your answer is okay. It's too bad we didn't receive any feedback of it yet. My disagreement is only about your first sentence about requestiong to change the title of OP. Also, you can see all revisions of the OP by clicking [editied .. ago](http://askubuntu.com/posts/540221/revisions) below the question above my avatar.

Comment: I modified the answer, the workspace is the main priority as you said. And thanks for the hint regarding the edit.
Speaking about the feedback - I would have liked to as more questions in form of a comment (are the proper packages installed, has the user moved .kde temporarily for a test already, etc.) , but for now I don't have enough points for asking questions.

Comment: I've been there. I know how frustrating this can be. Getting reputation with answers is pretty tough. But there are other means helping with AskUbuntu and gain the privilege to comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/495/how-can-i-increase-my-reputation-on-ask-ubuntu